# How can I check how many times the question was favorited?

Tags: support

Is there a way to check how many times my question was favorited on stackoverflow?

Comment: It should say so underneath the vote count. If it doesn't, then the question has no favorites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the star, underneath it is shown the number of times it has been marked as favorite

[image]

Or take another example and look at [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/292231/4516316) question, you can see that below the vote count, there is the favorite star and below it is the number of times it has been marked as favorite.